# Instantiating dependencies in spring

Tags: java, spring

Hi
If Class A is instantiated by spring. In class A i am Instantiating another object of class B ( regular intantiation using new operator) Can i instantiate the dependencies of class B just from insantiating class A??

```
class A{
    Xdao xDao;
    B bvar = new B();
}

Class B {
    Ydao yDao;
}
```

Is there a way to directly inject the dependency ob class B while instantiating class A??

is there something like:  ( dependecy attribute is just an example)

```
<bean id="classA"  dependecy="classB"> 
    <property name="xDao" ref="xDao" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="classB"  > 
    <property name="yDao" ref="xDao" /> 
</bean>
```

thanks in advance.

I want to avoid putting another property (or constructor) to set for nested call to class B
as I don't want to change existing code.

Comment: Please, format your java code as code (the 01010101 button). And add some linebreaks ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You should let Spring handle all the instantiation and injection**. This means that you should inject `classB` to `classA`:

```
<bean id="classA"> 
    <property name="xDao" ref="xDao" /> 
    <property name="bvar" ref="classB" /> 
</bean> 

<bean id="classB"> 
    <property name="yDao" ref="xDao" /> 
</bean>
```

And, get rid of your `new B()`:

```
class A {
    Xdao xDao;
    B bvar;
}

class B {
    Ydao yDao;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Neeme. I am just looking into spring docs i see there is depends-on attribute. Can i use that. As mentioned i don't want to change existing code which don't use spring injection yet but use new operator. Tks.

Comment: Spring has "depends-on" attribute but it is used for different purpose. If you want to use IoC container (such as Spring), you have to give up the right to construct new objects "by hand". So I guess you do not have any other choice than to change that existing code. Or do some crazy bytecode manipulation at class loading time, but that can be considered "black magic".

Answer (score 0):

The moment you call "new", that object is not under Spring's control.

Inject or call "new" - it's one or the other.